# Reorder values for plots

Tags: pine-script

I'm writing a code where the script finds some level of interest but due to the nature of the script, on the next candle, it might recalculate the same levels but assigning them to new plots creating unnecessary diagonal lines along the chart or blank spaces if I make the line transparent when the plots change value.

eg.

```
A[1] = 3
B[1] = 2
C[1] = 4
D[1] = 1

A = 2
B = 5
C = 3
D = 1
```

Is there a function or other way to keep a value to the same plot if the value was present also in the last calculation?

Comment: ` plot( D == D[1] ? D : na) `  ?

Comment: That's what I'm doing presently but it's creating gaps every time the plot changes value. I'm looking for a way to keep a value on the same plot it was on the previous candle